# PySide: How to override virtual method on object created from .ui file?

Tags: pyside

I am trying to use QWizard::validateCurrentPage from PySide.
My wizard class is loaded from .ui file using PySide.QtUiTools.QUiLoader

I created a function that supposed to override build-in QWizard::validateCurrentPage:

```
def validateDataPage(self):
    return False
```

Now I am trying to override build-in method like this:

```
    self.wizard = uiloader.load("registrationwizard.ui")
    f = types.MethodType(validateDataPage, 
                         self.wizard, 
                         QtGui.QWizard)
    self.wizard.validateCurrentPage = f
```

I see in debugger that validateCurrentPage is replaced:

```
self.wizard.validateCurrentPage
<bound method QWizard.validateDataPage of <PySide.QtGui.QWizard object at 0x04CC31C0>>
```

I can call it from debugger, but it is not called when I click "next" page.

Am I doing something wrong of it is not possible to override virtual functions when object is already constructed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should work since your way is the canonical way for [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object) in Python.

I made a small example and it seems to work for me.

```
import types
from PySide import QtGui

def overload(self):
    print(self.validateCurrentPage)
    return False

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
wizard = QtGui.QWizard()
wizard.validateCurrentPage = types.MethodType(overload, wizard)
wizard.addPage(QtGui.QWizardPage())
wizard.addPage(QtGui.QWizardPage())
wizard.show()
app.exec_()
```

prints

```
<bound method QWizard.overload of <PySide.QtGui.QWizard object at xx>>
```

Comment: Yes, but your validateCurrentPage overload will not be called as virtual method from C++. Try to do something in overload(self) and click next on wizard page.

From my tests it works only when you derive from QWizard and define overloaded method there.